# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 14 unable to open database file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, digital-ocean

I keep getting this error on my DO server. I have done chmod 755 on the sqlite. Can anyone think of this issue with them ?

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 14 unable to open database file
```

In regards to my server, i've recently upgraded to PHP7 and my phpini file looks like this.

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
 867 ;extension=php_curl.dll
 868 ;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
 869 ;extension=php_gd2.dll
 870 ;extension=php_gettext.dll
 871 ;extension=php_gmp.dll
 872 ;extension=php_intl.dll
 873 ;extension=php_imap.dll
 874 ;extension=php_interbase.dll
 875 ;extension=php_ldap.dll
 876 ;extension=php_mbstring.dll
 877 ;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
 878 ;extension=php_mysqli.dll
 879 ;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
 880 ;extension=php_openssl.dll
 881 ;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
 882 ;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
 883 ;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
 884 ;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
 885 ;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
 886 extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
 887 ;extension=php_pgsql.dll
 888 ;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

Comment: Have u given write permission to database file itself( I mean beside sqlite folder)?

Comment: yes 777 on .sqlite file

Comment: Are u using a shared host or  running the code on your localhost?

Comment: it's on my DO server @Peyman.H

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the file, the folder must also have permissions 777. IE if your sqlite file is in **database/database.sqlite** you may to chmod with 777 the folder (not recursive) and the file

```
chmod 777 database && chmod 777 database/database.sqlite
```